# malloc.c "sYSMALLOC: Assertion" in execution with C++ project

Tags: c++, malloc

**FINAL_EDIT: Found the problem, in a for loop the counter, that was used as an index as well, was greater than the number of the elements of the array. The weird thing about it, was that I wasn't receiving segmentation fault and instead the error I've mentioned. Why was that?**

**Thank you for your help!

*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

I have a project in C++ and am getting this error (NOT ALWAYS) and if a specific global   variable that acts as a size of an `int` array.

**NEW EDIT_1->I haven't used the `new` operator at all except for the main function that I am declaring a new array of pointers to objects of a class.
Like this:**

```
Student* test[NUM_AM];
for(int i=0; i<NUM_AM; i++)
{
     test[i] = new Student(random_elements);
}
```

Is there any way to find the line that causes this?

The error is this (copied the output of gdb):

```
malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) 
&((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) &&
 old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= 
(unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk,
 fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && 
((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff75563a5 in __GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c
```

Also valgrind gives this:

```
==6775== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6775==     in use at exit: 560 bytes in 35 blocks
==6775==   total heap usage: 35 allocs, 0 frees, 560 bytes allocated
==6775== 
==6775== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6775==    definitely lost: 560 bytes in 35 blocks
==6775==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6775==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6775==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6775==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6775== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6775== 
==6775== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6775== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==6775== ERROR SUMMARY: 806 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Thank you for your time.

**NEW_EDIT2:**
I ran the application with:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./out
and NUM_AM = 25;
```

This is the output I got is here at pastebin:  [here!](http://pastebin.com/xvkCVnCD)

**NEW_EDIT3:**
I should mention that the program creates students with an ID and assigns them a true/false value at a bool array and 2 bool variables.
The variable NUM_AM is used as an index of the static arrays declared as class members.
Also, NUM_AM is used in several functions when searching for their ID.

With NUM_AM > 22 the error can happen even after the creation of the 1st student.
With NUM_AM < = 21, I haven't been able to reproduce the error with multiple serial executions of the program.

Comment: Use `--leak-check=full` and `track-origins=yes`...

Comment: Doesn't it tell you what those 806 errors and 2 contexts were?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I have updated with the output of valgrind as extra information.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: No, it doesn't :S

Comment: No no, please no `--verbose` -- nobody cares about the suppressions... :-S And you need to compile with debug symbols, please: `-g -O0`.

Comment: There is a discrepancy in your for loop vs initialization: `NUM_ID` vs `NUM_AM`.  Generally gdb should give you a line number unless its happening during static initialization.  Try moving your global into an initialization function and call it from main.

Comment: @Tom Kerr: Sorry about that, it is NUM_AM and is defined at the 2nd .cpp file I have created as: 'const int NUM_AM = 25;'
out: malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

Comment: @TomKerr:
Continue-> 

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff75563a5 in __GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64 ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
 in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c

Also, I haven't quite understood what you mean with moving the global into an initialization function(what kind of function is that? a constructor?). Doing this move, wouldn't it mean that the global variable would result in being non-global? (if I do that a lot of compile problems will rise.

Comment: Could you check the trace to confirm that the error is happening where you expect it to happen? In gdb the 'bt' command prints you the trace. You can also print the local variables using 'p [expression]', but you need to first jump to the correct stack frame 'frame [idx]'.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I have changed the output of valgrind.
Also, compiled with -g -O0 but as I am a newbie in programming in general, I don't understand the output that much. This is the output
http://pastebin.com/qBUyJGnR

Comment: @CygnusX1: gdb with bt command gave me this http://pastebin.com/TKcs8H8g . What are the stack frames? :-S (newbie in programming)

Comment: possible duplicate of [sYSMALLOc: Assertion failed - any ideas how to debug effectively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317174/sysmalloc-assertion-failed-any-ideas-how-to-debug-effectively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you found the source of your bug. In relation to your final question

> The weird thing about it, was that I wasn't receiving segmentation fault and instead the error I've mentioned. Why was that?

If you allocate your array on the stack (e.g. your `test` is a stack array), accessing data beyond the bounds of an array does not raise the Segmentation Fault. Instead, you begin to override other, vital data on the stack. Stack contains:

- All your local variables
- The return address for your function (so that the function know where to return to)
- Previous frame pointers and other stuff necessary for correct function calling

Note, some or all of the above may be optimized out to some extend.
Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack