# malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, qt4

I am going to ask a stupid question. I have tried to solve this issue but failed.

Problem statement:

```
TCPSTUB: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

when ever I am executing my project getting the above error for a particular scenario.

```
following is the gdb snapshot for help:
```

[image]

Comment: You need to show your code in addition to the error you encountered.

Comment: @timrua.. that's true, but this projecthas 1000-1000 codes.

Comment: Then, try the tricks stated in http://stackoverflow.com/q/2317174/718379 first.

Comment: @timrau.. I have a log file that generally a trace log, but when i am getting the error , checked the trace log, it was in different place of my code, why this? each time error should happen in same place na? and calling a function is creating the error.if i comment that function it's runing successfully. But uncoomenting of that function error is geting before control goes to that function call statement.

Comment: You already know that it is a particular call to malloc which is being started in GeneratePacket::GeneratePacket() You should be able to set up debugs to identify where within that function the problem that eventually causes malloc to fail occurs. You can then check the appropriate values within the call to QTreeWidget() (which appears to be a library function) to see what the problem is.

Comment: `checked the trace log, it was in different place of my code, why this? `  Because a memory corruption error can affect any part of your program at any time.

Comment: Your answer to timrau seems to imply that you may be having an allocation not freed problem. Check your malloc() free() pairs. When debug statements cause a change in the behavior, that can mean that there is a buffer overrun that then causes problems later on. Since the change in the code causes additional memory assignments or allocations, the location in which the problem becomes visible will change.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317174/sysmalloc-assertion-failed-any-ideas-how-to-debug-effectively

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Learn how to use the `gdb` debugger and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)